# Add watermark from report parameter or from data set values

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

How to add watermark at run time in crystal report using 
any of the below procedure

1- Report parameter (simple text) to print on report

2- Report parameter (image path) to get image from path

Any other approach if better to display dynamic watermark?

Comment: What have you tried already? Stack Overflow is not a website to post coding problems and have someone else do it for you. I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and editing your question, as it is I have to flag it as 'too broad'

Comment: I have already implemented watermark using image that exists in my project directory using additional section in report by underlying section settings

Comment: Agree with you @MindSwipe but I have already implemented using image from project directory and that was simple so that I only have pdf file output so I dont need to put that pdf file as I only contains watermark from image in project directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal supports specifying an image path at runtime.
Right-click your static image on the report layout. Select 'Format Graphic'.
Select the 'Picture' tab.
Note the 'Graphic Location' allows you to enter a formula expression. Enter in that expression the dynamic path to the desired image.